# How to get array elements based on two indicies list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, indexing

```
z = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
index1 = [0,2,0,1]
index2 = [1,2,4,4]

# Kinda like manually doing
z[0][1]
z[2][2]
z[0][4]
z[1][4]
```

How do I use numpy to efficiently return the elements of array z based on the two indices lists (preferably flattened)?

Output:

```
>> array([ 1, 12,  4,  9])
```

Thanks

Comment: `z[index1,index2]`?

Answer (score 1):

as @Quang Hoang said it is as simple as

```
z = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
index1 = [0,2,0,1]
index2 = [1,2,4,4]

z[index1,index2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did I answer another question like this earlier? Anyway, I think you might want to read up on the numpy indexing page, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html. This will outline all the ways to index in numpy. I will give a brief overview.

There is essentially two indexing methods, BASIC which doesn't copy the data and simply lets you view the data in the array (and is accomplished by mainly slices and integer coordinates), and ADVANCED, which makes a copy of the data. In general, numpy behaves differently if you supply slices, ints, tuples, lists, or arrays, or boolean arrays.

In your example above it looks like you are interested in ADVANCED indexing. ADVANCED indexing is when you specify the coordinates of each point in a new array that you would like to make using another array. Numpy "knows" you want advanced because you are using lists to specify arbitrary coordinate access into the array. For example, suppose I want to make a (2,2) using the information in a (3,5). I want to access the coordinates at [[(0,0),(1,2)],[(2,2),(2,1)]]. We would do this:

```
z = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
#   1st dim         2nd dim
z[  [[0,1],[2,2]],  [[0,2],[2,1]]  ]
```

If we want to create a (4,) instead, we would do:

```
z = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
#   1st dim     2nd dim
z[  [0,1,2,2],  [0,2,2,1]  ]
```

The two examples above are EXPLICIT. Every coordinate has been specified. Of course numpy is smarter than just EXPLICIT. In the event that the 1st dim array and the 2nd dim array are not the same shape, then python assumes you wanted those arrays to be broadcast together. Take for example,

```
z = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
#   1st dim     2nd dim
z[  [[0],[2]],  [1,2,2,3,1]  ]
```

Here we have accessed the rows 0 and 2 and columns 1,2,2,3,1. This broadcast to a (2,5) shape, since the first coordinate was a (2,1) and the second was a (5,). This broadcasting works in exactly the same way as any other broadcasting in numpy, like for example, adding two arrays. If the 1st dim and 2nd dim arrays cannot be added together then they cannot be used for indexing either. Lets check:

```
np.array([[0],[2]]) + np.array([1,2,2,3,1])
```

This produces the same shape as the example above, but at each place we have added the x coordinate and y coordinate together, instead of using them to access a value at the x and y coordinate in another array. Note: np.array([0,2]) + np.array([1,2,2,3,1]) cannot be broadcast together, hence you need the extra [] around the 0 and 2.

Anyway, hope this helps.